# How can a Reddit moderator preset text in the blank TEXT field?

Tags: reddit

##### How do Reddit moderators preform text in the TEXT field? See picture below.

I moderate a medical SubReddit like [r/AskDocs](https://old.reddit.com/r/AskDocs/submit?selftext=true). I need to automate text to appear in the text field whenever someone submits a post, to remind them to provide context.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]!  Please take the [Tour] and also review [ask] Please review Creesch's subreddit [Creating and moderating a subreddit 101](https://www.reddit.com/r/creesch/wiki/mod101/ ".../r/creesch/wiki/mod101/") which is the first result returned by googling either "[moderating reddits](https://www.google.com/search?q=moderating+reddits "...search?q=moderating+reddits")" or "[moderating subreddits](https://www.google.com/search?q=moderating+subreddits "...search?q=moderating+subreddits")"  If you have a problem following your review, [edit] your question with additional detail.

Comment: I believe that's subreddit CSS. You can ask about this at https://www.reddit.com/r/modhelp/